# Freenas gave wrong mount command to /mnt freenas filesystem

Tags: freebsd, bsd, zfs, mount-point, umount

My colleague made a mistake and gave:

```
mount -t nfs freenasip:\mnt\backup \mnt
```

on FreeNAS server itself instead of other server where it was to be mounted. Immediately he ran:

```
umount freenasip:\mnt\backup
```

but it hanged. Now both `mount -a` and `zfs mount -a` on FreeNAS show correct info but `cd /mnt/` or any folder inside `/mnt` hangs at the prompt. Also, file sharing and NFS mounting to external server issue. Is there any way to resolve the issue without a reboot?

I have iscsi targets service running in it so have to wait for all servers to shutdown and then reboot FreeNAS which will resolve the issue. Is there another solution for same?

Comment: Have you tried _zfs unmount -f <file system>_ or would that not be a desirable solution in your situation?